# Changing Mongoose schema type not working

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema with a property which was a string array.

```
docs: [String]
```

I changed the type to an object array as follows

```
docs: [{ url: String, type: String }]
```

But when I create a new item, the docs field is still validated with the type string and the following error is thrown.

[image]

I even tried dropping the collection and it still not works.

Comment: Wouldn't that be `docs: [{ url: String, type: String }]` ?

Comment: @temp_user yeah. typo. edited

Answer (score 1):

The brackets should be around the type, and not the entire object.
As documented [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#Arrays),
instead of your Schema being:

```js
docs: [{ url: String, type: String }]
```

It should be

```js
docs: { url: String, type: [String] }
```

Comment: That was a typo. Edited

Comment: sec editing my answer to be more clear